# Mongodb - geospacial _id?

Tags: mongodb

I currently have a collection of small documents.  Each document has an indexed geospacial field and *the default _id is never used in any query*.  There will never be more than one document related to a particular geo location.  I think it makes sense to override the default _id, and use the geospacial data for this somehow.

**Question is, how do you use geospacial data as the unique id?**  Is it a case of creating a flat string from the geo field?  E.g. 'x123456y123456'?

Answer (score 2):

The _id field is the unique identifier for each document and thus is a needed field. The _id field is generated on document creation automatically if one is not provided. If you can provide this geospaital value when creating the document you should be able to use the string as you suggested, you cannot use an array as the _id value. However please be aware that once a document is created the _id becomes unchangeable. This means that using the _id field as a meaningful index of geospatial data may not be of much value.

Have a look [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField) for more info on the _id field and [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing/) for some information about creating geospatial indexes in Mongo

Comment: Thanks, I've read both of those docs, but I didn't see anything on storing geo data in the id.  Probably string is way to go then.  In my case, geo data will never change for a particular document.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: are you trying to use MongoDB's [geospatial indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing/) features .. or just storing string values for manipulation in your application?